# Configure repeatInterval for local notifications in iOS in react-native

Tags: ios, react-native

I am using `PushNotificationIOS` API in `react-native` to schedule local notifications for my mobile app. I want to configure repeating local notifications for the app and I see that there is an option to configure `repeatInterval` for local notifications in native iOS but I didn't find any such option in the `PushNotificationIOS` API. If anyone has configured `repeatInterval` for local notifications in `react-native`, please let me know.

I think I would need to add the functionality into the `PushNotificationIOS` API to also accept a `repeatInterval`. So, I checked how to configure `repeatInterval` in native iOS and found that I need to use instance of `NSCalendarUnit` to configure the repeat interval. I don't have any experience in `objective-c` and not sure how to convert the `repeatInterval` from `js` to `objective-c`.

Comment: Check out this PR: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/7219

Comment: @DanielBasedow Thanks for pointing to the PR. I searched for `repeatInterval` in the `react-native` `Issues` but didn't get any hits for some reason but this is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for PR. It helped me.